# Knockout sub/pub notification received twice

Tags: knockout.js, publish-subscribe

My first KO project has an editor Component that "apply"s a base class for common functionality and implements a child "Buttons" Component to provide templated Save/Cancel/Reset buttons and related event handling.

The "Buttons" component needs to handle click events and advise the Editor base class which then decides how to deal with it.

I wanted to use KO's Pub/Sub functionality to handle the communication and first tried the knockout-postbox plugin, but kept getting a double-publication so I have pared it down to a basic pub/sub setup, to no avail.

The 'Click' event fires only once and has it's propagation stopped, but the notification is received twice.

Clearly I am doing something wrong but I am at a loss to what it is...

Can anyone see why the noted Alert would be firing twice?

App.js

```
 var appViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.postbox = new ko.subscribable();
    return new appViewModel();
 })
```

Buttons.html

```
<div class="nav btn-group editButtons">
    <button class="btn btn-default" data-bind="click:reset">Reset</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" data-bind="click:cancel">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click:save">Save</button>
</div>
```

Buttons.js

```
define(['App/app','jquery', 'knockout', 'text!./editorButtons.html', 'strings'], function (app,$, ko, htmlString) {

  function EditorButtons(params) {
     var self = this;
     var clickTopic = "{0}EditorButtonClicked".format(params.namespace);

     // **** THIS FIRES ONCE *****
     self.save = function (me, e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        app.postbox.notifySubscribers("save", clickTopic);
        return false;
     }
  }
  return { viewModel: EditorButtons, template: htmlString };
 });
```

EditorBaseClass

```
define(['knockout', 'jquery', 'App/app', 'strings'], function (ko, $, app) {

    EditorBaseClass = function (parent, item, mode, namespace) {
        var self = this;
        self.mode = ko.observable(mode);
        var clickTopic = "{0}EditorButtonClicked".format(namespace);


        // **** This Alert fires Twice *****/
        app.postbox.subscribe(function (clickType) {

            alert(clickType);

        }, self, clickTopic);
    }
});
```

Parent Editor

```
define(['jquery', 'knockout', 'App/app', 'text!./myEditor.html', 'models/EditorBaseClass'], function ($, ko, app, htmlString, editor) {

    function MyEditor(params) {
        var self = this;
        EditorBaseClass.apply(self, [self, params.item, params.mode, "myNamespace"]);
    }
    return { viewModel: MyEditor, template: htmlString };
});
```

Thanks for anything you might spot - I can go back to JQuery events but I'd like to have this in my toolkit.

Comment: Can you recreate this using a fiddle?

Comment: You may used this [plugin](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox) for your application pub/sub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've understand from your example, it seems that you want to publish and subscribe to a certain channel (e.g. "save"). That being said, I would change the following:

```
 self.save = function (me, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    // you should use ko.postbox to publish to a channel
    ko.postbox.publish("save", clickTopic);
    return false;
 }
```

and

```
// also also use ko.postbox to subscribe to a channel
ko.postbox.subscribe("save", function (clickType) {
    alert(clickType);
});
```

A full example can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ecx9kw1p/). I've tried to keep your original code so it's easier for you to pick up.

P.S. I think it is better for you to take a closer look at the [knockout-postbox documentation](https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox) since it seems that you are missing the basics.

Comment: thanks very for the working fiddle, it does work with the postbox plugin. Just a note - my code doesn't look like postbox plugin code because it isn't. The variable 'postbox' is a simple ko.subscribable and the code is my attempt at implementing KO's native pub/sub facilities /without/ the plugin as described here : http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html - that all said I did get it working, and appreciate the pointer :-)